# Question on the amount of binary bits operations in binary division.

Tags: proof-explanation, cryptography, binary

*For the question, we write $\ell(a)$ to denote the length of the positive integer $a=(a_1\cdots a_k)_2$.*

In my cryptography textbook, in the section of binary division, I found the following claim:

> Let $a\geq b\in \Bbb{Z}^+$. Then, the binary division $a:b$ requires
>   $\leq \ell(b)\cdot(\ell(a)-\ell(b)+1)$ binary bit operations.

Τhen, in order to prove the claim, it continues:

From the division algorithm, $\exists \ a,b\in \Bbb{Z}^+: a=bq+r,\ 0\leq r<b.$ And from an easy to prove theorem, we know that $\ell (q) \leq\ell(a)-\ell(b)+1.$

Now, finding the quotient and remainder requires $\ell(q)\leq \ell(a)-\ell(b)+1$ subtractions.
subtractions.

*Each subtraction requires $\ell (b)$ bit operations*.

**And in this sentence above I faced the problem.**

**Why do we have $\ell(b)$ bit operations instead of $\ell(a)$?**

For example:

[image]

In this example we have $2$ subtractions. In the first $(1101-1001)$ we have $4=\ell(b)$ binary bits operations. But, in the second $(10001-1001)$ we have $5>\ell(b)=4$ binary bits operations.

Why does this happen? Do I misunderstand something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You know the result of the subtraction will be less than $b$, so you don't have to carry out the subtraction of the highest-order bit (because you know the result will be $0$).